# How to apply the same color animation on two elements?

Tags: animation, svg

Is there a way to apply the same color animation on two elements ?

Something like `xlink:href="#item1, #item2"`

[Here's a pen to test it](http://codepen.io/alienlebarge/pen/Kwyjoa?editors=100).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

SMIL Animations are per element. You could use javascript to [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) the animation so you have two copies and then point each copy at a separate element.